# C code - time functions return different results on Debian Linux and OpenWRT

Tags: c, linux, time, openwrt

Can you help me with this code ? Can you explain why receive different results with same code in Debian and Openwrt ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <syslog.h>

int main (void){

  char *on_time = "16:45:00"; 
  char *off_time = "19:20:00";

  struct tm *tm_on;
  struct tm *tm_off;
  struct tm *tm_curr;

  time_t t_on_time, t_off_time, t_curr_time;
  time_t t_now, t_now_on, t_now_off;

  t_now = time (NULL);
  t_now_on = time(NULL);
  t_now_off = time (NULL);

  tm_curr = localtime (&t_now);
  tm_on = localtime (&t_now_on);
  tm_off = localtime (&t_now_off);

  t_curr_time = mktime (tm_curr);



  syslog (LOG_INFO, "CURRENT TIME IS : %ld is: %s", t_curr_time, ctime (&t_curr_time));

  if (sscanf (on_time, "%d:%d:%d", &tm_on->tm_hour, &tm_on->tm_min, &tm_on->tm_sec) == 3)
    {

      syslog (LOG_INFO, "TM_ON : %s", asctime(tm_on));
      t_on_time = mktime (tm_on);
      syslog (LOG_INFO, "ON TIME IS      : %ld is: %s", t_on_time, ctime (&t_on_time));
    }


  if (sscanf (off_time, "%d:%d:%d", &tm_off->tm_hour, &tm_off->tm_min, &tm_off->tm_sec) == 3)
    {
      syslog (LOG_INFO, "TM_OFF : %s", asctime(tm_off));
      t_off_time = mktime (tm_off);
      syslog (LOG_INFO, "OFF TIME IS     : %ld is: %s", t_off_time, ctime (&t_off_time));
    }

  if (((t_on_time <= t_off_time) && (t_curr_time >= t_on_time) && (t_curr_time <= t_off_time)) ||
      ((t_off_time < t_on_time) && ((t_curr_time <= t_off_time) || (t_curr_time >= t_on_time))))
    {
      printf("SWITCH ON\n");
    }
  else
    {
      printf("SWITCH OFF\n");
    }

}
```

Results in Debian :

```
Oct 29 18:25:18 s2 helloworld: CURRENT TIME IS : 1477754718 is: Sat Oct 29 18:25:18 2016
Oct 29 18:25:18 s2 helloworld: TM_ON : Sat Oct 29 16:45:00 2016
Oct 29 18:25:18 s2 helloworld: ON TIME IS      : 1477748700 is: Sat Oct 29 16:45:00 2016
Oct 29 18:25:18 s2 helloworld: TM_OFF : Sat Oct 29 19:20:00 2016
Oct 29 18:25:18 s2 helloworld: OFF TIME IS     : 1477758000 is: Sat Oct 29 19:20:00 2016
```

Results in OpenWRT :

```
Oct 29 18:25:25 192.168.11.200 syslog: CURRENT TIME IS : 1477754725 is: Sat Oct 29 18:25:25 2016
Oct 29 18:25:25 192.168.11.200 syslog: TM_ON : Sat Oct 29 18:25:25 2016
Oct 29 18:25:25 192.168.11.200 syslog: ON TIME IS      : 1477748700 is: Sat Oct 29 18:25:25 2016
Oct 29 18:25:25 192.168.11.200 syslog: TM_OFF : Sat Oct 29 18:25:25 2016
Oct 29 18:25:25 192.168.11.200 syslog: OFF TIME IS     : 1477758000 is: Sat Oct 29 18:25:25 2016
```

Where is the error ? Why result is different in OpenWRT ?
Any suggestions ?

Comment: maybe one is using localtime while the other is using UTC, relevant article on arch [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time)

Comment: I would have assumed a timezone problem, too but with timezone problems the dates woul dbe off some half/full hours, yours is that it seems  to ignore the different input completely and shows current time only. OpenWRT uses uClibC, AFAIK, so what's the version (Macros needed listed somehweer here: https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Libraries/)? But uClibC is quite mature, so I don't expect a bug there but one never knows.

Answer (score 0):

What is your timezone? Is it by chance GMT +02:00, and you have a timezone set on the Debian box but not on the OpenWRT router?

You can avoid these issue by replacing `localtime()` with `gmtime()` and redo all your time comparison at GMT / UTC.

Here is a *much simpler* example (somewhat reworked):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void){

  struct tm *tm_curr;
  time_t t_now;

  t_now = time (NULL);
  tm_curr = localtime(&t_now);
  printf("Local: %ld %s", t_now, asctime(tm_curr));

  tm_curr = gmtime(&t_now);
  printf("GMT  : %ld %s", t_now, asctime(tm_curr));

}
```

I use `asctime()` to actually print from the `struct tm`.  You see the difference between localtime (Central for me, and set) which affects the first row when I set it (arbitrarily) to Berlin:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ ./timeex 
Local: 1477755946 Sat Oct 29 10:45:46 2016
GMT  : 1477755946 Sat Oct 29 15:45:46 2016
edd@max:/tmp$ TZ="Europe/Berlin" ./timeex 
Local: 1477755960 Sat Oct 29 17:46:00 2016
GMT  : 1477755960 Sat Oct 29 15:46:00 2016
edd@max:/tmp$
```

However, the results of the `gmtime()` call is unaffected by the value of `TZ` and always what UTC aka GMT is.

The **really key takeaway** is that `time_t` is UTC in both cases, but `struct tm` is not.  You have to be clear about *what* you are comparing *where*.

Computing with times and timezones is a hassle.  I generally prefer C++ for this over C, but it is good to work through this once or twice at the C level.

Comment: Timezone are same EEST. If you see logs Epoch is same but result of ctime and asctime are different.

Comment: See my expanded answer with a simplified example.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that :  1477748700 is: Sat Oct 29 18:25:25 2016 is not right.  That is on Openwrt but the right output is that : 1477748700 is: Sat Oct 29 16:45:00 on Debian

Comment: The OpenWRT, as I conjectured, likely has no timezone information.  Which is why it falls back to UTC.  I showed you how to deal with the problem in UTC time.